# Selenium - How to Wait For an Element's Text to no longer be empty?

Tags: c#, string, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, is-empty

Was struggling with a conditional wait. Out of the box there is a method to wait for a text to be present.
Alas, no such thing for the text to no longer be there.

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver.Browser, Timeouts.Process(timeout)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(this.Selector.Locator, text));
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver.Browser, Timeouts.Process(timeout)).Until(d => d.FindElement(this.Selector.Locator).Text != text);
```

Which I then call with text = ""

Comment: For anyone using Selenium C# and have to make sure if a text box is empty use this  ---->
new WebDriverWait(Driver.Browser, Timeouts.Process(timeout)).Until(d => d.FindElement(this.Selector.Locator).GetAttribute("value")!= text);